# How to escape string in onClick="function(string)"

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to echo a string that could contain everything into the following html line:

`<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="function(<?php ... ?>)">...</a>`

I don't know how to properly escape the string I pass with php, there seem to be many problems and json_encode is not working as it wraps the output in double quotes which is not working as the double quotes already begin after "onclick=".

Just replacing single quotes also doesn't work as "\'" would be replaced to "\'".

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add the code which you tried with example text

Comment: try to use **onclick='<?php ... ?>'**

Comment: The problem is not about echoing something into the line. It is preparing the string that I echo so that it does not break the string in onclick="".

Answer (score 1):

you can use **addslashes(**) function.
Try this:

```
<?php 
    $str = addslashes('What does "yolo" mean?');
    echo($str); 
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the html parser seems to ignore the backslash before the double quote: `onclick="function('test\"test')">`

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.addslashes.php) function:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="function(<?php addslashes($YourParameter) ?>)">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As none of the answers worked, I had a closer look at the problem and came up with this solution:

```
function clean_param($string){

  // escapes all single quotes and backslashes
    $single_qu_esc = addcslashes($string, "'\\");

  // escapes the resulting string for html
    return htmlentities($single_qu_esc, ENT_QUOTES);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can wrap your string with htmlspecialchars, that should do the job.

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="function('<?=htmlspecialchars('can"be;anything')?>')">...</a>
```

Comment: He wants to escape quotes, not to use HTML special characters. This would cause problems in his JSON...

Comment: On what esle than JSON would he use json_encore?

Comment: Missed that :) saw only "string that could contain everything"

Comment: I nearly missed it myself, it is not very clearly written :)